# How to catch, why request is not mapped in Spring Web?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have the following mapping:

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/", params = "!op")
   public Iterable<User> getUserList() {
      return userRepository.findAll();
   }
```

and I also have the following mappings (probably conflicting):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", params = "op=delete")

@RequestMapping(value = "/",params = "op=update")
```

while entire class has a mapping

```
@RequestMapping("/user")
```

On startup I have the following messages in the log:

```
2015-12-26 20:11:25.103  INFO 5796 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/user/],params=[op=update]}" onto public com.inthemoon.pdk.data.User com.inthemoon.pdk.web.UserController.addUserByScreenName(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
2015-12-26 20:11:25.105  INFO 5796 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/user/],params=[op=delete]}" onto public com.inthemoon.pdk.data.User com.inthemoon.pdk.web.UserController.deleteUserByScreenName(java.lang.String)
2015-12-26 20:11:25.105  INFO 5796 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/user/],params=[!op]}" onto public java.lang.Iterable<com.inthemoon.pdk.data.User> com.inthemoon.pdk.web.UserController.getUserList()
```

Unfortunately, the discussed mapping does not work, i.e. when I request

```
http://localhost:8080/user
```

the mapped method not triggered.

Why?

Is it possible to turn on logging so that I track, how Spring decides, where to map a request?

Comment: Don't have an answer for your question but you should consider using URI params rather than query params for the operation. I.e. have `/user/update` (no query params) mapped to `update()` method rather than `/user/?op=update`.

Comment: Just remove `!op` ... Spring MVC will try to do a best match anyway.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have added "!op" since it was not working without it too.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen yes, have tried and nothing happened (no method triggered)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `!op` is intended to mean 'without an `op` parameter' then just remove it as suggested.

The reason `http://localhost:8080/user` doesn't reach your `@RequestMapping` is because it is missing the trailing slash (i.e. the slash you have in your `@RequestMapping` on the method). If you remove `!op` and make a request to `http://localhost:8080/user/` the request should be mapped as you expect.

Comment: How to map both with and without trailing slash?

Comment: You can use `@RequestMapping(value = {"/", ""})` to map requests to both with and without the slash.